# Need to put semicolon at the end of last line

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want to put semicolon only at the end of the second line (or the last line) not the first.

Taking three strings in an array: `String[] = {"My first string", "My second string", "My last string"};`

My current output:

```
My first string;
My second string;
My last string;
```

I need output in the form:

```
My first string My second string My last string;
```

Comment: uhh, we don´t even know how you print it, how should we know what you are doing wrong and where the `;` is coming from.

Comment: What you've done to achieve it? where is your code? What is the condition, you need it only at the last line or at the second and last line?

Comment: I am using a for loop for the array for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {append(array[i].append(";"));}, I am doing something like this.

Comment: i need it only at the last line

Comment: What does your `append` method do, as well? The best answer will depend on the details here.

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Edit it into the question where it belongs.

Comment: You should have read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something in this way.

```
String outputString;

for(String str : yourString) {
  outputString = outputString + str;
}

outputString  = outputString  + ";" ;
```

Other option:

> There is the Arrays.toString() method, which will convert an array to
>   a string representation of its contents. Then you can pass that string
>   to System.out.println or whatever you're using to print it.

For example :

```
  String newString = Arrays.toString(str).replace(",", " ");
  newString = newString.substring(1, newString.length()-1)+";";
```

Output :

> My first string  My second string  My last string;

Comment: Concatenating strings in a loop like this is a bad idea... it's O(n^2) for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        append(array[i].append((i == array.length-1) ? ";" : ""));
    }
```

Note that the use of ternary operator will check for the last element of the array. Using this you can control the appending of the a semicolon or a blank

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, with something like:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] sarr = {"My first string", "My second string", "My last string"};
        String sep = "";
        for (String s: sarr) {
            System.out.print (sep + s);
            sep = " ";
        }
        System.out.println(";");
    }
}
```

It simply outputs out each string in the array, preceded by a separator (initially an empty string but a single space after the first array element is output).

Then, at the end, it outputs the semicolon and newline:

```
My first string My second string My last string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below.. it may help

```
String[] string= {"My first string", "My second string", "My last string"};
string[string.length-1]+=";";
```